# As a web-master how should I deal with Malware browser plugins?

Tags: javascript, malware, malware-detection

I have client-side javascript error logging.
It has revealed some of my pages are affected by malware installed in users' browsers, potentially impacting user experience / sales.

Example malware causing javascript errors:

- eshopcomp
- Yontoo

Example errors:
**Yontoo**

```
at Function.m.parseJSON line 4, column 15739 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:4)
     at ? line 47, column 428 (http://serviceama-a.akamaihd.net/js/intext.js:47)
     at m.event.dispatch line 3, column 8436 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:3)
     at r.handle line 3, column 5146 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:3)
```

**eshopcomp**

```
at Function.n.scaleOnResize line 5, column 7710 (https://pstatic.eshopcomp.com/nwp/v0_0_571/release/Shared/App/SharedApp.js:5)
     at ? line 5, column 6509 (https://pstatic.eshopcomp.com/nwp/v0_0_571/release/Shared/App/SharedApp.js:5)
```

Comment: Same thing came up in my error logs, I usually am associating their user account & email with the error reports.  So i just send them a curtesy email to let them know.  I guess if you wanted to be super badass you could write a script that does this automatically.